# Metadata API Custom Field Permissions (how to automate this process)

Tags: custom-field, metadata-api, permissions

We are using the Metadata API to add Custom Fields to the Account object in Salesforce.  We are able to create the custom fields, but then the Salesforce user has to manually login to their account and set the Field-Level Security to "Visible" for each Custom Field.  Is there a way to set the visibility of the field or to set the permissions for the fields we add via the Metadata or Soap API's when we add the fields?

Comment: There  is already a [post][1] in stack exchange.Please look at it.


  [1]: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34521/set-field-level-security-for-profile-using-meta-data-api

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We saw that post, but we were wondering if there was a direct method within the Metadata API.  Maybe defining a PermissionSet (metadata.permissionset) using the API functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We answered the question (with suggestions from sfdcfox in this thread and blogs by Terry Luschen).  We provided a detailed description of our answer at the [Salesforce Developer Forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AVifIAG).

We still have some outstanding issues regarding support for Dynamic Custom Fields for users with Salesforce Profession Edition and on record limits when using the SOAP API to transfer data.  Any guidance on those topics is welcome.

Comment: Without salesforce actively enabling the org for API access, you cannot access those orgs via metadata API. Only the SOAP and REST API (CRUD operations) are supported for partners at this time. The usual policy is never to enable the API for GE, and only for a limited time on PE. See also the ISVForce guide for details on accessing orgs using client id (SOAP) or a connected app with bonus permissions (REST).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment (or the documentation).  Does using a Connected App allow for Custom Fields to be added to the standard Account or Contact objects if your PE user?

Comment: My apologies for any confusion. No, there is no way to access the metadata API in PE or GE without having the API turned on for that org. This comes by either buying it a la carte, or asking nicely, in which case it may be temporarily enabled.

Comment: That coincides with what I'm reading.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I recently got asked about this, the MD update API does work when adding FLS to a profile, however it only works if you send just what you want. Here is an example using the Apex Metadata API wrapper, but the principle is the same in other languages, https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/68#issuecomment-70227907

Answer (score 3):

If you have an existing PermissionSet you can use an associated [FieldPermissions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_CSH.htm#sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm) to grant Read permissions. This can be done via the Partner API.

Set the:

- `Field` to 'Account.CustomField__c' (where CustomField__c is the API name of your field)
- `ParentId` to the ID of the existing PermissionSet,
- `SobjectType` to 'Account'
- `PermissionsRead` to true

Comment: A permission set isn't necessary, though.

Comment: @sfdcfox Perhaps not. As you answered, profile based access may be preferable. PermissionSets would be more applicable if the field access didn't align with the current profiles.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Profile object in the metadata API to deploy object and field level permissions for the new object/fields. [Read the documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your replies - We've looked at both your comments and Daniels comments, plus the documentation (and many threads), but we still don't understand how to implement the permission change.  There is something basic we're missing.  We've added the Custom Fields using a create call [metaCustomFieldsResult = myMetaService.create(metaCustomFields)], and we've looked at declaring field level security [Dim fieldSecurity As New sfMetadata.ProfileFieldLevelSecurity], but we can't determine how to access the custom fields in the "Account" object and then to apply the new security values.

Comment: @csMaps When I get a moment, I'll give you an update.

Comment: We've made some additional discoveries (by doing a Select of the Field Permissions table in the Developer Console). All of the Custom Fields we created have PermissionsEdit and PermissionsRead set to true (so that's not the problem). If we log into Salesforce and check the System Administrator visibility property in the Field-Level Security, the custom field now works and is listed in our [myService.describeSObjects({"account"})] call. The missing visibilities seems to be our problem. Is there a setting in Salesforce that our customers need to enable/disable? Or can we adjust in the API?

Comment: @csMaps I was going to update this answer when I got home, but basically you just need to deploy field level security with the fields. This is done with the profile metadata object. You can do this via API. Something like: query all standard profiles, generate object and profile payload, then deploy. You can deploy both new fields and profile permissions at once.

Comment: This is unbelievably hard for something that should be very easy!!  We've started doing queries in the Developer console, looking at PermissionSets associated with 'Standard' Profiles, and looking at FieldPermissions.  All of the fields appear to be set correctly, so we have no idea which field we want to change that is equivalent to setting the Field-Level Security to visible in the UI.  Plus we have no idea how to deploy in the Metadata API without having to generate external packaged Zip files.

Comment: One additional thought.  We've now noticed that when we add the fields from the Metadata API in our Development environment the Field-Level Security is properly set (without us setting any permissions). However, when we publish our website to the server, and a user clicks to set up our Salesforce interface, the fields get built, but none of the Field-Level Security visibility settings are checked.  Maybe we need to add a deploy (or check it's status) after we submit our custom field create. Or, should we be looking at the wsdl file (to add our Server IP)?

Comment: @csMaps The FLS in the UI is the fieldPermissions[] array on the Profile metadata object. If you want to use the synchronous REST API, you can do so, but that's painful: deploy object, deploy fields (10 at a time), deploy profiles (10 at a time). If you use the ZIP method, preferred, you can package the entire thing up at once. The API isn't suppose to set any FLS on fields unless specified, so if it is by some chance, perhaps you're doing it accidentally-- stranger things have happened. I do think you'll want to check your WSDL and code.

Comment: OK, we are now attempting to use the ZIP method. We put a detailed discussion at the SF [Dev Forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AVifIAG).  See the second note.  First question is do we need to retrieve a package file first? We created a CustomObject.xml file with our Custom Fields, and then a Profile.xml file for our fieldPermissions.  Finally we added a Package.xml (which we don't think we have configured properly) and then zipped it all up and attempted to load it.  The load works with out error, but the status coming back indicates a success of false.

Comment: @csMaps you simply need to make sure it lists all the correct elements. You can check the monitor deployments area in setup to view deployment failure reasons.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance/patience on this issue.  It shows "Deployment Succeeded", but with 0 components.  There are no error messages, and no custom fields.  We think our Package.xml file is wrong, but have no idea what to change. Please see our other [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000AVifIAG).  Do we need to list all of the fields in the package.xml file instead of the "*"?  Any ideas on what to change, how to test, or where to read?

Comment: We updated the files/code at our other link.  We found some incorrect element names and realized that we are using Version 29.0 of the API (not 30.0).  Turns out the Profile doesn't support "description" until 30.0, so we removed that element.  We are now receiving a "Payload Error" in the Deployment Status area with a detail of "No package.xml found".  We tried renaming the file to adjust for case, but are still having the issue.  Must be something with reading the zip file.  Should we deploy one file at a time?

Comment: The file should be called package.xml, and it should be in the root folder of the zip file. This sounds kind of pesky, but I'd really like to help you get to the bottom of this. Perhaps you could email me and I could take a peek at the file, see how it's constructed, and give you better advice?

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions (and your offer to email you) and sorry about the delay in getting back to you.  Between your comments in this thread and the blogs of Terry Luschen mentioned in our answer, we have come up with a solution to our problem.  I posted an Answer here with a link to the detailed description we created at the Salesforce Developer Forum.