# Update fieldPermissions with metadata api of Salesforce

Tags: metadata-api, custom-field, permissions, soap

I try to update the permissions on a field created from the API so that it is visible and usable.

so I do this via the salesforce metadata API.

```
responses = client.call(:update_metadata, message_tag: :updateMetadata, message: {metadata: { fullName: 'Admin', fieldPermissions: {field: "Contact.custom_attribute1_soap__c", editable: true, readable: true}}, :attributes! => {metadata: {"xsi:type" => "Profile"}}})
```

`client` is an instance of the gem Savon.

which gives me this, and seems correct to me !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header>
      <tns:SessionHeader>
         <tns:sessionId>s3ss10n1d</tns:sessionId>
      </tns:SessionHeader>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <tns:updateMetadata>
         <tns:metadata xsi:type="Profile">
            <tns:fullName>Admin</tns:fullName>
            <tns:fieldPermissions>
               <tns:field>Contact.custom_attribute1_soap__c</tns:field>
               <tns:editable>true</tns:editable>
               <tns:readable>true</tns:readable>
            </tns:fieldPermissions>
         </tns:metadata>
      </tns:updateMetadata>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

however, salesforce sends me back a mistake. 
After hours of searching the documentation I don't understand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unable to determine type mapping for type Profile.  Type is illegal here.</faultstring>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

One of you could explain my mistake to me, or give me a method to modify the permissions on a custom field created via the API, please?

Comment: What API call did you make when the "Unable to determine type mapping for type Profile" fault response came back?

Comment: It's a call to the API soap metadata the URL looks like this: `https://um4.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/39.0/<ID>`

Comment: So you are trying to update the field permissions on the Admin profile via the metadata API, correct?

Comment: yes, I have created custom fields via the SOAP API and I need them to be visible and editable by the user and by the API.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve the same result, without using the SOAP API ?

Comment: Why do you need SOAP API? You can easily achieve this in Apex since FieldPermissions is available to Apex SOQL queries and DML operations.

Answer (score 0):

One way to update the field permissions via the APIs is with the [FieldPermissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm) that are exposed via the Partner API.

You can update the `PermissionsEdit` and `PermissionsRead` fields fairly easily. Use the `ParentId` to find the PermissionSet.

This is touched on in [Metadata API Custom Field Permissions (how to automate this process)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/36917/102)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the attribute `"xmlns": "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"`

Try:

```
responses = client.call(
    :update_metadata,
    message_tag: :updateMetadata,
    message: {
        metadata: {
            fullName: 'Admin',
            fieldPermissions: {
                field: "Contact.custom_attribute1_soap__c",
                editable: true,
                readable: true
            }
        },
        :attributes! => {
            metadata: {
                "xsi:type" => "Profile",
                "xmlns": "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
            }
        }
    }
)
```